# form_for called in a loop overloads IDs and associates fields and labels incorrectly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, loops

Rails likes giving all of my fields the same IDs when they are generated in a loop, and this causes trouble.

```
<% current_user.subscriptions.each do |s| %>
  <div class="subscription_listing">
    <%= link_to_function s.product.name, "toggle_delay(this)"%>
    in <%= s.calc_time_to_next_arrival %> days.
    <div class="modify_subscription">
        <%= form_for s, :url => change_subscription_path(s) do |f| %>
            <%= label_tag(:q, "Days to delay:") %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:query) %>
            <%= check_box_tag(:always) %>
            <%= label_tag(:always, "Apply delay to all future orders") %>
            <%= submit_tag("Change") %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', s, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Produces

```
<div class="subscription_listing">
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_delay(this); return false;">Pasta</a>
    in 57 days.
    <div class="modify_subscription">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/subscriptions/7/change" class="edit_subscription" id="edit_subscription_7" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="s5LJffuzmbEMkSrez8b3KLVmDWN/PGmDryXhp25+qc4=" /></div>

            <label for="q">Days to delay:</label>
            <input id="query" name="query" type="text" />
            <input id="always" name="always" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <label for="always">Apply delay to all future orders</label>
            <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Change" />
</form>     <a href="/subscriptions/7" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="subscription_listing">
    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_delay(this); return false;">Gummy Bears</a>
    in 57 days.
    <div class="modify_subscription">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/subscriptions/8/change" class="edit_subscription" id="edit_subscription_8" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="s5LJffuzmbEMkSrez8b3KLVmDWN/PGmDryXhp25+qc4=" /></div>
            <label for="q">Days to delay:</label>
            <input id="query" name="query" type="text" />

            <input id="always" name="always" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            <label for="always">Apply delay to all future orders</label>
            <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Change" />
</form>     <a href="/subscriptions/8" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And that's a problem because now no matter which "Apply delay to all future orders" I select it always very helpfully checks the first box for me.  How can I override the ID without doing something ugly and un-rails-like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to override the id by passing it in as an option

```
text_field_tag(:query, '', :id=>'unique id')
check_box_tag(:always, '1', false, :id=>'unique_id')
```

For instance

```
<% current_user.subscriptions.each_with_index do |s,i| %>
  <div class="subscription_listing">
    <%= link_to_function s.product.name, "toggle_delay(this)"%>
    in <%= s.calc_time_to_next_arrival %> days.
    <div class="modify_subscription">
        <%= form_for s, :url => change_subscription_path(s) do |f| %>
            <%= label_tag("query_#{i}", "Days to delay:") %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:query, '', :id=>"query_#{i}") %>
            <%= check_box_tag(:always, '1', false, :id=>"always_#{i}") %>
            <%= label_tag("always_#{i}", "Apply delay to all future orders") %>
            <%= submit_tag("Change") %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', s, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```